# Two New Kittens

Tags: cats, behavior, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets, new-pets

I just adopted two kittens. Sibling brothers. Both of these kittens were born on 11th of September making them about 15 weeks old.  They were raised at a horse farm by loving people but I’m worried in that rural area they didn’t have much chance to socialize.  I brought them home last night and they have been hiding all night. No eating. No playing. No using the litter box. I put them in the bathroom with limited exposure.  I’m worried they may not adjust to be family pets for my kids.   Anyone have a similar experience?  How long to I give before I think of giving them away?

I have a home with a right and two year old....  and a Golden.  I really was hoping the kittens would be part of my family.  Is it possible they will never like us?

Help!

Comment: "I have a home with a right " what do you mean? No, the kittens will settle down, but they will need some special care to make them feel safe so they can trust you.

Answer (score 3):

Kittens in a new home will be scared of all the new smells, sounds and sights and it's expected that they will hide for a while, especially after the trauma of being taken from their mother. The more familiar (and therefore comforting) things they have, and the smaller the space they have to explore, the faster they will adjust. A sibling in particular is great, but you should also use the same food (hopefully wet so they can smell it) and litter. They may not yet recognize your food dish and litter box as such, though eventually they will learn to expect food and litter in them regardless of changes in smell or location over time.

The key to socialization is getting them to associate humans with food, like they used to with their mother. Cats become feral when they learn to find sufficient food on their own after weaning and thus see no need for humans. As long as they haven't hit that stage, which seems unlikely at only 15 weeks, you still have a very good chance.

Cats can get very ill, potentially fatally, if they don't eat for as little as 2-3 days, so take them to a vet for assistance if you don't see any sign of them eating soon.

Do not introduce them to children or other pets until they're comfortable with your home and any adults in it, eating well and using the litter box regularly.